# I need to have a simple contract for sending ether from one account to another account with specified values?

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

contract sendEther{

address payable rec= address(0xD694fab8b63BeF0149aa47b8333dFeAe7f55E9C7);
address public sender = msg.sender;


function send() public payable{

    rec.transfer(msg.value);

}

}
```

I need to send a specific value to that address mentioned. This is to be included in my Dapp. So i need to send a specific amount to any specific address and the input amount have to be injected by the user

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to send ether to a ethereum address with a specific amount?

Comment: Like the message sender have to send a specfic value of ether to the above address so what is the necesity

Comment: msg.value is the amount you would send to the contract first, then the contract address holds those ethers (virtually) and redistributes/sends the ethers with .transfer function. So the amount is dynamic here (as much as you send to the contract will be retransfered). You could of course hardcode the amount in msg.value.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a contract for that, just send a transaction. Your app can generate a transaction with the value input by the user to the address and ask the user to sign it (metamask).

Hope this helps